# jquery autocomplete textbox does not work with master & content pages in ASP.NET

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, master-pages

I have a master page in which I have the following code.

```
<head runat="server">
    <link href="StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" runat="server" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js"></script>
    <asp:contentplaceholder id="LocalScripts" runat="server"></asp:contentplaceholder>
</head>

<body id="body" runat="server">
    <form id="form1" runat="server" defaultbutton="SignOutLB">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </form>
</body>
```

My content page has the following code.

```
<asp:Content ID="ScriptContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="localScripts" runat="server">
<script type="text/javascript">
    function suggest(inputString)
    {
        if(inputString.length == 0) 
        {
            $('#suggestions').fadeOut();
        } 
        else 
        {
            $('#AAATB').addClass('load');
            $.post("AutoSuggest.aspx?ST=" + inputString, function(data){
                if(data.length >0) 
                {
                    $('#suggestions').fadeIn();
                    $('#suggestionsList').html(data);
                    $('#AAATB').removeClass('load');
                }
            });
        }
    }

    function fill(thisValue) 
    {
        $('#AAATB').val(thisValue);
        setTimeout("$('#suggestions').fadeOut();", 600);
    }
</script>
</asp:Content>
```

And the ASP.NET code is as follows.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="AAATB" runat="server" Width="90px" MaxLength="6" onkeypress="return IsNumberKey(event)" CssClass="textboxStyle" ValidationGroup="projNoValGp" onkeyup="suggest(this.value);" onblur="fill();" />
<div class="suggestionsBox" id="suggestions" style="display: none;"> 
    <img src="Images/arrow.png" style="position: relative; top: -2px; left: 50px;" alt="" />
    <div class="suggestionList" id="suggestionsList"> &nbsp; </div>
</div>
```

My AutoSuggest.aspx has the following piece of code.(I have done this for testing. Once the functionality works, I will change this for retrieving data from the database.)

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] arr = new string[] {
                        "1234",
                        "1111",
                        "1333",
    };
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        Response.Write("<li onClick=\"fill(\'" + arr[i] + "\');\">" + arr[i] + "</li>");
    }
}
```

This works up to the extent that the values "1234", "1111", "1333" are displayed. But when I choose one of these values it is not reflected in the textbox "AAATB".

I would be grateful for all the help to solve this issue.

Thanks,
Carolina

Comment: can you see if the js-method fill() is called at all? Either by debugging or adding an alert-statement to the function.

Comment: Yes, it is called. But I could see that the parameter "thisValue" is undefined.

Comment: Hmm..that's really strange. Can you verify how the li-tags are rendered in your browser (by using FireBug or IE Dev Toolbar)?

Comment: I did using IE. But it does not show the <li> tags at all. For your reference I have added the screen shots.

Comment: If you click the refresh button (next to save-button) in IE toolbar after the autocomplete-options have showed up, they will show up in the toolbar as well.
Btw, I cant see the screenshots?

Comment: Sorry, am not able to attach the screenshots. 
However I did as you said and finally could catch that piece of code. It looks perfect to me. Since I am not able to attach the screen shot, I am pasting the code for you to check.

<div class="suggestionList" id="suggestionsList">
    <li onclick="fill('1234');">
        Text - 1234
    <li onclick="fill('1111');">
        Text - 1111
    <li onclick="fill('1333');">
        Text - 1333

Comment: I think I have an answer for you, see below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I know. You use '#AATB" as selector for the textbox. However, this is a serverside-ID and will be rendered differently on the client.
Try using this as your fill code:

```
function fill(thisValue)
{
    $('.textboxStyle').val(thisValue);           
    setTimeout("$('#suggestions').fadeOut();", 600);
}
```

The idea is to use the css-class as selector for the textbox since this isn't modified.

Comment: The idea you gave was the right one. However, the piece of code mentioned above was not suitable for me as it filled all the textboxes on the screen with the selected value.  
  
So, I just made a little bit of change to it as follows  
    function fill(thisValue)  
    {  
        $("#<%= AATB.ClientID %>").val(thisValue);  
        setTimeout("$('#suggestions').fadeOut();", 600);  
    }  
and it works.  
Thank you for your timely help!

Comment: No problem, glad that I could help out!